# Ng-bootstrap and bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, ng-bootstrap

Is Ng-bootstrap needed now that bootstrap 5 no longer includes jQuery?  I wanted to know if there are any changes to future support/updates.

I’m starting a new project using Angular with bootstrap and don't want to use a wrapper if it’s not needed.